# North Cyprus on Schengen Visa

Tags: visas, schengen, pakistani-citizens, cyprus, northern-cyprus

I am a Pakistani National currently residing in Hungary with a Hungarian residence permit that allows me to travel visa-free throughout the Schengen zone. I also know that i can travel to south Cyprus using that residence card. Will I be able to cross into northern Cyprus or do I need a separate visa for that?

Answer (score 6):

Your Pakistani passport suffices. Holders of every passport except the Federal Republic of Nigeria and the Republic of Armenia can enter Northern Cyprus for up to 90 days without a Visa. Check the [Visa Regulations](https://mfa.gov.ct.tr/consular-info/visa-regulations/) for other requirements:

Foreigners are required to have the following in their possessions at the port of entry to the TRNC:

- A valid passport
- £85 (Sterling Pounds) or equivalent per day the visitor intends to stay
- Round trip ticket
- Proof of confirmed hotel reservation
- For visiting family or friends, a letter of invitation which provides name, address, phone number and other contact information in full
- If traveling for higher education, an official acceptance letter from the university
- If traveling on a business trip, an official letter of invitation from a company in the TRNC

Comment: Can you travel directly from Southern to Northern Cyprus? The relationship between both of them are not pleasant.

Comment: https://www.gov.uk/foreign-travel-advice/cyprus/safety-and-security says "It’s possible to travel to the north of Cyprus from the south (and back again)." So yes, first going to Southern and only then to Northern (and back) is OK. If, on the other hand you fly to Northern Cyprus first and then go to the south , you will have trouble.